# what is the difference between Math.E and e

Tags: java, math, double, scientific-notation

So if I run

```
System.out.println(1e+0);
```

it outputs 1

however if i run

```
System.out.println(Math.E);
```

it outputs 2.718.........

for the life of me I cant figure out how the little e interacts with numbers 
I get that Math.E is a constant that has something to do with logarithms 
but I thought the little e was just that being represented in a number yet the code is showing me something different. 
can anyone explain how that e interacts with numbers in java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal `1e+0` is [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for `1 * 10⁰`, and `10⁰` being `1` this gives `1 * 1`, thus `1`.

The constant `Math.E` is [Euler's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).

Comment: ok so, 1 is the base number. e defines that it is in scientific notation. the plus sign is redundantly stating that it  is a positive exponent.  and 0 is the power that 10 is being raised to, is that all correct?